# How to use an If-statement whilst looping through multiple rows

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Is it possible to use two different cell ranges in an if-statement and then have a result of that if-statement inserted into another range?

Code:

```
If Range("H3:H26").Value > Range("K3:K26") Then Range("N3:N26").Value = "Over"
ElseIf Range("H3:H26").Value < Range("K3:K26") Then Range("N3:N26").Value = "Under"
ElseIf Range("H3:H26").Value = Range("K3:K26") Then Range("N3:N26").Value = "Good"
Else: Range("N3:N26") = "No"
End If
```

I understand why having a two different ranges in an if-statement wouldn't work but I'm trying to find a way to have this code work without having multiple if statements for different rows

Comment: There is no loop in your provided code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use comparison operators with arrays in VBA. When you do `Range.Value` with a multicell range, you are creating a 2D array. Comparison Operators like `>` and `<` only work with individual values, not with arrays of values in VBA.

You need to loop through the rows, checking each cell from H3:H26 and K3:K26 as individual values.

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 3 To 26
        If Cells(i, "H").Value > Cells(i, "K").Value Then
            Cells(i, "N").Value = "Over"
        ElseIf Cells(i, "H").Value < Cells(i, "K").Value Then
            Cells(i, "N").Value = "Under"
        ElseIf Cells(i, "H").Value = Cells(i, "K").Value Then
            Cells(i, "N").Value = "Good"
        Else
            Cells(i, "N").Value = "No"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You can use an If Statement or the much cleaner looking Select Case statement

```vb
Sub ExampleLoop()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 3 To 26
        Select Case Cells(i, "H").Value
        Case Is > Cells(i, "K").Value
            Cells(i, "N").Value = "Over"
        Case Is < Cells(i, "K").Value
            Cells(i, "N").Value = "Under"
        Case Cells(i, "K").Value
            Cells(i, "N").Value = "Good"
        Case Else
            Cells(i, "N").Value = "No"
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

You could also not need to loop or use any if statement by making use of the `IF` formula in excel.

```vb
Sub ExampleFormula()
    Range("N3:N26").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(H3>K3,""Over"",IF(H3<K3,""Under"",""Good"")),""No"")"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Compare Two Columns

[image]

**Usage (The Calling Procedure(s))**

```
Sub TestSimple()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet 'improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("K3:N26")
    CompareTwoColumns rg, 1, 4, 7, "Over", "Good", "Under", "No"

End Sub

Sub TestChecks()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet 'improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("K3:N26")
    
    Dim Compared As Boolean
    Compared = CompareTwoColumns(rg, 1, 4, 7, "Over", "Good", "Under", "No")
        
    If Not Compared Then Exit Sub

    MsgBox "The comparison finished successfully.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**Help (The Called Procedures)**

- The first one is actually a method written as a function utilized in the `TestChecks` procedure.
- The second is called only by the first.

```vb
Function CompareTwoColumns( _
    ByVal SourceRange As Range, _
    ByVal FirstColumn As Long, _
    ByVal SecondColumn As Long, _
    ByVal DestinationColumn As Long, _
    ByVal StringGT As String, _
    ByVal StringEQ As String, _
    ByVal StringLT As String, _
    ByVal StringElse As String) _
As Boolean
    Const ProcName As String = "CompareTwoColumns"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Dim rg As Range
    ' Source
    Set rg = SourceRange.Columns(FirstColumn)
    Dim fData() As Variant: fData = GetColumnRange(rg)
    ' Compare
    Set rg = SourceRange.Columns(SecondColumn)
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = GetColumnRange(rg)
    ' Destination
    Set rg = SourceRange.Columns(DestinationColumn)
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = rg.Rows.Count
    Dim dData() As String: ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)

    Dim fValue As Variant
    Dim sValue As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    Dim dString As String
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        fValue = fData(r, 1)
        sValue = sData(r, 1)
        If VarType(fValue) = vbDouble Then
            If VarType(sValue) = vbDouble Then
                Select Case fValue
                    Case Is > sValue: dString = StringGT
                    Case sValue: dString = StringEQ
                    Case Is < sValue: dString = StringLT
                End Select
            End If
        End If
        If Len(dString) = 0 Then
            dData(r, 1) = StringElse
        Else
            dData(r, 1) = dString
            dString = vbNullString
        End If
    Next r
    
    SourceRange.Columns(DestinationColumn).Value = dData
    CompareTwoColumns = True

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    MsgBox "' Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, ProcName
    Resume ProcExit
End Function


Function GetColumnRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    Optional ByVal ColumnNumber As Long = 1) _
As Variant
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If ColumnNumber < 1 Then Exit Function
    If ColumnNumber > rg.Columns.Count Then Exit Function
    
    With rg.Columns(ColumnNumber)
        If rg.Rows.Count = 1 Then
            Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = .Value
            GetColumnRange = Data
        Else
            GetColumnRange = .Value
        End If
    End With

End Function
```